# How to show a div on top of the page in fixed position?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having some issues to keep my `Loaded-Content` *image* on a position:fixed.

My Container loads an hidden content by clicking the button, with a transition the loaded content should slide from the right to Left. Its should be always on the top.

The loaded-content `<div class="sticky">cat image</div>` should always be  fixed on the top. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<div class="container">many photos</div>
<button>LOADED-CONTENT comes in transform(translateX(0%)</button>
</html>

<html>
sticky image always on top.
<button>back button slides the loaded content transform(translateX(100%)</button>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6kpnN/

Comment: Its already working check it http://jsfiddle.net/KbNwG/1/

Comment: @Dholakiya Ankit Doesn't! if you scroll the main container and then you click CLICK u can see that the page is not on the top.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6kpnN/1/

Comment: @Dholakiya Ankit Not sure if you understand my point? try and scroll down the container then Click the button. the G00gle image should be on the top of the page
http://jsfiddle.net/6kpnN/2/

Comment: Not sure still how your output should looks like?

Comment: @Dholakiya Ankit  the GOOGLE image should slide in always on the top. If I slide down with the Container then I click the button, the next page should slide on the top of the page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50594/discussion-between-sanguisuga-and-dholakiya-ankit)

Comment: Just `#load-content {position: fixed;}` After transition you can hide page below and change css if needed.

Comment: Please check my answer : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/23493287/3222831](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23493287/3222831)

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS and specity that div class to be always on top

```
<style>
.sticky
 {
  position: fixed;   
  top : 0px;
  left : 0px;
  width : (specify) ;
  height : (specity here);
  }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with css

```
#IdName{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NiccoW3/QYy96/)

you can learn css [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/DEFAULT.asp)

Answer (score -1):

You should always learn more about CSS before you actually use it.

In this situation, a few attributes will be used :

- `width`
- `top`
- `left` (or `right`)
- `position`

The whole code is this :

```
.selector {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; /* Or right:0; */
    width: 100%; /* Or change it if you want */
}
```

Change `.selector` to the [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) you need.

Use [`position:fixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) to fix the position in the page.
Specifying the [`top`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp) makes the distance from the top of the page and the element to be 0 all the time.
Specifying the [`left`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp) / [`right`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_right.asp) will also fix the distance between left / right and the element.
Finally, specifying the [`width`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) will make a bar on top of your page.

Please, always search for it before you ask : [Search](http://is.gd/searchYourself)